# How to store a file (xml) requested by http into an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get a xml file, which I can request by an http request into an object.
I'm looking for something similar to this (in a controller):

```
@ticket = request "http://example.com?ticketid=1234"
```

http://tickets.com?ticketid=1234 returns an XML (tickets.com is not the site the app is running on).

I then want to parse @ticket, to get the data out of the xml.

Thx a lot for all your help!

Comment: Do you want @ticket to contain the XML or to actually be an instance of a class that reflects the data represented by the XML?

Comment: I didn't think about that yet. Yes I will want to get out the data of the xml after that, to continue working. I didn't look at how I have to handle this afterwards (I'm pretty new at programming, so I'm taking things step by step).
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to download the XML into a string, the following would do:

```
require 'open-uri'

xml = URI.parse("http://example.com?ticketid=1234").read
```

If you want to parse this XML and extract the data, you need to look at
some kind of parser, e.g. [LibXml](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/) or [Nokogiri](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master).

If you're trying to access data from another Rails application, maybe *ActiveResource* is the way to go. Here's a nice [introduction](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HTTParty](http://railstips.org/2008/7/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited) for super easy consumption of web services.  Basically, you'd do something like this:

```
class Ticket
  include HTTParty
  format :xml
end

@ticket = Ticket.get('http://url/to/ticket')
```

Then you can access elements in a hash:

```
@ticket['title'] # => the <title> element
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the xml data you can use the Active Support Hash extension to convert it into a Hash

```
xml = URI.parse("http://example.com?ticketid=1234").read
data = Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

This way you don't need extra libs and figure out to traverse the xml. YMMV

Note: not sure how this method handles element attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hpricot XML method](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot/hpricot-xml) like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'hpricot'

@ticket = Hpricot.XML open "http://example.com?ticketid=1234"
```

Then you can easily parse `@ticket` with Hpricot dynamic methods. See some examples in the Hpricot page.